# How do I put three reasons together in a sentence?

Tags: commas, logic, reasoning

> In conclusion, as there is no incentive for the people to contribute,
> the government becomes dangerously dictatorial, and corruption is
> widespread, socialism does not work.

By the above sentence, I want to convey that as there is no incentive for the people to contribute, **and** as the government becomes dangerously dictatorial, **and** as corruption is widespread, socialism does not work.

I can see that I've already committed the heinous crime of comma splicing: ", the government becomes dangerously dictatorial," is a complete sentence separated by commas. How do I form a cogent sentence expressing my ideas?

Comment: "In conclusion: as that there is no incentive for the people to contribute, as that the government becomes dangerously dictatorial, and as that corruption is widespread, socialism does not work."

Answer (score 2):

One option is to move the conclusion before the reasons:

> In conclusion, socialism does not work as there is no incentive for the people to contribute, the government becomes dangerously dictatorial, and corruption is widespread.

In terms of style, you may not like this if you want to end with the conclusion clause, so another way is to turn your reasons into a list of noun phrases headed by "due to":

> In conclusion, due to the lack of incentive for the people to contribute, governments becoming dangerously dictatorial, and widespread corruption, socialism does not work.

Comment: I ended up writing like this, "In conclusion, as there is a lack of incentive for the people to contribute, a dictatorial government, and widespread corruption, socialism does not work". Is it okay?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic That works if you're talking about a real situation in a real country where Socialism isn't working. "There is" means that list of things exists now in a real present situation in one country. If that's the case, then yes

Answer (score 1):

You could do exactly what you did when explaining your intent:

> In conclusion, **as** there is no incentive for the people to contribute, **as** the government becomes dangerously dictatorial, **and as** corruption is widespread, socialism does not work.

You don't need a second "and" before "as the government", and indeed some prescriptivist grammarians would even argue that it's incorrect to have it there, even though it's perfectly understandable and quite widely used and can work quite well in terms of prosody.  (See what I did there?)  But you *should* repeat the word "as" for each reason, since it helps the reader understand that those *are* reasons rather than conclusions, so that they won't be surprised and won't have to reparse the whole sentence when they get to the actual conclusion at the end.

---

Ps. [Gotube's suggestion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/328934) of moving the conclusion to the front is also good, but even then, I'd still be inclined to repeat the "as":

> In conclusion, socialism does not work **as** there is no incentive for the people to contribute, **as** the government becomes dangerously dictatorial, and **as** corruption is widespread.